# How to call a static objc method from swift with id<SomeProtocol, NSObject> type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In the header file I have

```
+(id<SomeOtherType,NSObject>) getInstance: id<SomeType,NSObject>) connection error:(NSError**)error;
```

And I struggle to call it from the swift.

I already have a reference to `SometType` object, but how do I pass it to the `getInstance` method?

```
var error : NSError!
let connection : SomeType = myConnection;
let device = Factory.getInstance(connection, error: &error)
```

obviously doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Create a objc wrapper is the easiest way to deal with it

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Make a wrapper class do all the thing you want in objc, and expose a simple interface to swift. Since if both protocol are defined in objc, the above code you shared should work. So i assume you are defining swift protocol and use in objc id type constraint.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewLuiHK Indeed easiest thing.